# projective space and torus

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

we defined the projective space as $\mathbb{S^2/Z_2}$ i.e. identify antipodal points and the torus as $\mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2.$

And now I am concerned with their manifold structure-

In fact, I managed to cover both of them with three charts and it is also immediate to me that one chart cannot cover them, because they are compact, so their image would be compact under a homeomorphism. Despite, I don't see why two charts cannot cover them. Is there an easy argument for this?

Comment: FWIW, a torus _can_ be covered by two annular charts; think of gluing two U-shaped tubes at their ends.

Comment: http://math.ucr.edu/~res/math246A/cuplength.pdf Requires some knowledge of cohomology and cup products, but gives an answer in the case of the torus. (Slightly stronger statement than what you asked for, since they consider covers by open sets with nullhomotpic inclusion maps.)